# How to render a static list of multiple Key,Value Pairs in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am rendering at the moment a listview where each item is rendering again a listview. To remove an exception I set the inner listview property shrinkwrap to TRUE.

Now I can not scroll the outer grid anymore ONLY when I grab/tap the mouse pointer between the items of the outer listview. The inner listview shows the bouncing blue effect when I try to scroll.

I do not want  that the outer listview scroll stops working.

The inner list should just be rendered as a plain static list of TWO key/value pairs just like:

```
1 tests  01:30 time
3 tests  00:05 time
2 tests  15:10 time
```

I am a flutter beginner so is there any better way than the nested listview?

Comment: It's not an answer, I know, but is it really necessary using a ListView for so little items? I suggest you to use `Row` for such a scenario

Comment: Please share your code. We can't help you without it.

Comment: @JoãoSoares sure you can and please do not speak for others...

Comment: @Tizianoreica yes normally there not more than 5-6 different tests, thats it.

Comment: Just in case, to follow up your first question, you can use a `NestedScrollView` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html) to have a ListView inside a ListView, I would still suggest to use a simple Row for the inner List

Comment: @Tizianoreica Thanks with some Nesting of Column(Container(Row( 2 Key/Value Pairs))) I could render it out. It just needs some good formatting like space between the keys/values.